# How to link data from a table to another table in sqlite database?

Tags: database-design, sqlite

I need to link data from a table to another table. I'm not sure how to do this. I have never link a table to another table. Anyone can help me? Or maybe can give me examples or sample codes? Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an idea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22642/sqlite3-simple-database-design-question) that seems to work. Generally speaking though, you can do this like this:

```
Table1
------
table_key
data_type1
data_type2


Table2
------
table_key
table_key_in_table1 (linked to table1)
data_type1
data_type2
...
```

And so on.